# SQL how to use LIKE/NOT LIKE to find anomalies?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm trying to find anomalies in my Social Security Number column where the SSN is not written like
"XXXXXX-XXXX". I've tried using this query:
`SELECT employee_name, employee_team FROM employee WHERE employee_ssn NOT LIKE '%0-9%-%0-4%'`.

It always returns every employee, even if I deliberately change the SSN of an employee to have the wrong values.

How do I write the query so that it returns any cases where the SSN is not written in the form above, including the "-" sign?

Comment: Try REGEXP_LIKE?

Comment: `SELECT employee_name, employee_team FROM employee WHERE instr(employee_ssn,7,1)<>'-' or length(trim(employee_ssn))<>11`

Comment: mysql like operator only supports _ and % and escape sequences, you need regexp_like (rlike) for this